# Get Control from FooterTemplate of Repeater

Tags: c#

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <tr>
          <td class="menu">
          <a href="/Contact.aspx">Pomoč in podpora</a>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChangeUser" runat="server" CssClass="childrenSelectType" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false"                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlChangeUser_SelectedIndexChanged">
          </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
    </tr>
```

How can i get ddlChangeUser control from FooterTemplate of repeater.

This is not ok, becouse it is not in ItmeTemplate.

```
 DropDownList ddlChangeUser = siteMapAsBulletedList.Items[0].FindControl("ddlChangeUser") as DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ItemDataBound event and in there check for Footer.

```
siteMapAsBulletedList.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(siteMapAsBulletedList_ItemDataBound);

...

void siteMapAsBulletedList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        DropDownList ddlChangeUser = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlChangeUser");
        if (ddlChangeUser != null) {
                   ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but is there no any other possibility to get DropDownList from FooterTemplate?

Comment: @senzacionale - nope, not as far as I know. What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: i need to get some ID in if (ddlChangeUser != null) { but i can not get it then

Comment: @senzacionale - get what ID? Why can't you get it?

Comment: @senzacionale sorry can't see the problem. You can have whatever code you want inside that if {} block - post the error you get and I'll try to guide you through it.